# I cant connect to internet

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I've installed Ubuntu recently on my PC (dual boot), and it worked fine for the first day, but then the next day I couldn't connect to Wifi; [the Wifi menu doesn't appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m534n.png) when I login, and when I change the USB port for my Wifi adapter, the Wifi menu appears, [but it's stuck on connecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfwDh.png). longest time I've waited for it to connect was approximately 20 mins (and it didn't connect), I've tried restarting the PC and the router, but nothing has worked so far.

This is my WIFI adapter: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TvuD.png), It works just fine on windows 10.

and I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS